# How to send different objects from Client to Server, and deal with each object depending on its type?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I'm currently building a message-exchange program. I want to send data to my server in two separate occasions:

1. When a new user logs in/signs up, to verify the user's information. This goes in a User object that contains username, password representation, salt, and public key;
2. When the actual message is sent. Each message is sent in a Message object, containing the message, the sender, the destination, and the time.

I want my server to check if the object being received is of type User, and verify that information, or if it's of type Message, and forward the message.

This is what I'm doing, but it doesn't seem to work as it throws a java.io.EOFException.

```
try {
   if (objectInputStream != null) {
      if(objectInputStream.readObject().getClass() == incomingUser.getClass()) {
         System.out.println("OBJECT IS AN USER");
         incomingUser = (User) objectInputStream.readObject();
         System.out.println("Name: " + incomingUser.getName());
      }
      if(objectInputStream.readObject().getClass() == m.getClass()) {
         System.out.println("OBJECT IS A MESSAGE");
         m = (Message) objectInputStream.readObject();
         System.out.println("NAME:" + m.getDestination());
      }
   }
} catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Exception**

```
java.io.EOFException
   at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:3171)
   at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1630)
   at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:493)
   at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:451)
   at sample.Server$ClientHandler.run(Server.java:76)
   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Plus, when sending an User, the machine recognizes it is an User object being sent before throwing the exception, but not when it's a Message.

**Complete Client Code**

```
public class Client {
   public void run() {
      String host = "127.0.0.1"; //local host
      int port = 4333;

      try (Socket s = new Socket(host, port)) {

         System.out.println("IP Address: " + host);
         System.out.println("Connecting...");

         OutputStream outputStream = s.getOutputStream();
         ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);

         User user = new User("daniela");

         Message m = new Message("test1", "test2", "test3");

         objectOutputStream.writeObject(m);

         System.out.println("Connection successful!");
      }
      catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

   }
}
```

**Complete Server Code**

```
public class Server {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ServerSocket ss = null;
      try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(4333 );
            ss.setReuseAddress(true);

      while (true) {
            Socket client = ss.accept();
            System.out.println("New client connected: " + client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
            System.out.println("\n");
            ClientHandler clientSock = new ClientHandler(client);

            new Thread(clientSock).start();
      }
   }
   catch(IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
   finally {
      if( ss != null) {
            try {
               ss.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
      }
   }

}

private static class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
   private final Socket clientSocket;

   public ClientHandler(Socket clientSocket) {
      this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {

      InputStream inputStream = null;
      try {
            inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
      } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
      }
      ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = null;
      try {
            objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
      } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
      }

      User incomingUser = new User("");
      Message m = new Message("test", "test","test");

      try {
            if (objectInputStream != null) {
               if(objectInputStream.readObject().getClass() == incomingUser.getClass()) {
                  System.out.println("OBJECT IS AN USER");
                  incomingUser = (User) objectInputStream.readObject();
                  System.out.println("Name: " + incomingUser.getName());
               }
               if(objectInputStream.readObject().getClass() == m.getClass()) {
                  System.out.println("OBJECT IS A MESSAGE");
                  m = (Message) objectInputStream.readObject();
                  System.out.println("NAME:" + m.getDestination());
               }
            }
      } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I get on the right path?

Comment: _"it throws a java.io.EOFException"_ - You can [edit] your question and include the full stack trace of the error. You can also clarify which specific line of code is throwing the error.

Comment: You're calling `readObject` twice. Once to get the class, then again to get the actual object. This will read *two objects* and discard the first. Read the object once before your `if` statements.

Comment: @tgdavies If I read tbe object before the `if` statement, how will I get the right object? Since it can be either a User or Message. I can't write `m = (Message) objectInputStream.readObject();` if the Server is getting a User-type object

Comment: From your stack trace: `at sample.Server$ClientHandler.run(Server.java:76)`. Which line is line number 76? We can't see your line numbers.

Comment: @andrewjames sorry, its the `if(objectInputStream.readObject().getClass() == m.getClass())` line

Comment: Just write `Object o = objectInputStream.readObject()`, then you can cast it later when you know what class it is.

Comment: ...which is indeed the second `readObject` call. So store the object in an `Object` first, as already suggested: `Object obj = objectInputStream.readObject()`. Then you can test that object as needed.

Comment: `readObject` is not doing anything different based on what cast you are performing on the result. It just reads the next object in the stream. The type it reads is determined by what's in the stream, not by the caller.